# Facing issue with alert message in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

Why alert pop up is behaving like this in IE10? Not facing the same issue in IE8 and 9. Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1><center>Sample program to test Pop up hang</center></h1>
    <script>
      alert('test');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[[image]]

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1><center>Sample program to test Pop up hang</center></h1>
<script>
alert('test');
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you please explain your question a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: When I am running above code in IE8/9 I can click on pop up screen and scroll it throughout the screen but when I do the same in IE10 I can see no scrolling of alert pop up. It is covering entire screen. Can you check screenshot. I am novice to this portal hence don't know how do I attach  a snapshot here.